# Find out who make at least $10000 less than the 50000

Tags: meaning

Suppose that: John makes $20000. Sara makes $40001. Peter makes $45000.

If I want to find out who "make at least $10000 less than the 50000.", what should be the answer?

My idea is that Sara and Peter are the ones. But someone else said that John is the one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a math questions, not an English question.

Comment: This phrasing is not anything anybody would use if they weren't trying to trick the responder.

Comment: It is confusing.  "(At least 10000) less than 50000" or "At least (10000 less than 50000).  One of the reasons mathematics is often expressed in symbols rather than words.

Comment: If this is coming from a non-native speaker, who is working in a data-analysis position, than I think this could very well be as much of an English issue as a math issue. If OP thinks they are clearly conveying one mathematical idea (with English) and being mistaken, the issue is with the English, not with math.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, "making $10,000 less than $50,000" puts the cutoff at $40,000.

Next is too decide if "at least" means we include the people who make more than $40,000 or those who make less.

"At least .. [descriptor]" indicates than we want the cut-off case, and cases more extreme. In this case, since "making $30,000 less" is more extreme than "making $10,000 less", that means we would  include **John**.

Looking at Sara, she only "makes $9,999 less than $50,000". This is not "at least $10,000 less than $50,000". The same holds true for Peter as he only "makes $5,000 less than $50,000".

---

This sounds like phrasing that is intentionally confusing, or forced to be phrased this way for some reason. Usually we use "at least" to indicate "at this level or higher". However in this case we mean "at this level or [more] lower", and this is because of the **less** included.

This would be better phrase as:

> Who makes less than $40,000.

---

For a similar exercise (that doesn't involve math):

> Consider an ant, a pig, a house, and the Earth. Which objects are at least as small as Mount Everest?

This question is asking which objects are smaller than Mount Everest. Therefore the answer is "an Ant, a pig, and a house".

---

---

**EDIT:** I think the phrasing of this is slightly ambiguous, so its intended meaning should be clarified by the speaker. I would then use one of the following options:

> Who makes at least $40,000?
>
> Who makes less than $40,000?

If the 10,000 and 50,000 are variable, it may be helpful to use math notation. However, make sure the audience will understand:

> Who makes at least (Y-X)?
>
> Who makes less than (Y-X)?

in this case Y is the reference salary ($50,000) and X is the difference ($10,000).

Comment: Thanks. the three instances are just made up by me. In reality there are many other data and employee

Comment: I see, I am now questioning my answer ... I think the sentence itself is worded ambiguously and could be take either way.

Comment: I agree it could be read either way (so if it's your sentence, maybe better to rephrase) but I think the reading *(at least 10k) less than 50k* is much more plausible than the reading *at least (10k less than 50k)* because it makes sense of the fact that 50k is mentioned. If the first meaning was intended, you would just say *at least 40k*. If you take the 50k to be some sort of threshold, and the speaker to be interested in how far off the threshold people are, then the sentence makes perfect sense.

Comment: Your answer is correct, a more usual example is the advertising of sales offering "At least 50% off" which means that the items are offered at half price or below. However some sales are offered as "At least half price" which always sounds ambiguous to me as something offered at twice its normal price is "at least half its normal price", but that's probably my cynical and suspicious mind!!

Comment: @BoldBen Reminds me of shops that offer sales of "Up to 50% or more off on all items!"

Comment: @Minty, your comment brings out clearly that the ambiguity here is what is qualified by *at least*; would you consider turning it into an answer?